# How to get Euler angles from Spherical Coordinates?

Tags: rotations, spherical-coordinates

I'm trying to rotate a cylinder by the same amount of its location on a sphere. For example, I have a cylinder with midpoint at $R = 100$ cm, $\theta = 30$ degrees, $\phi = 45$ degrees using the ISO convention where theta is the polar angle and $\phi$ is the azimuth angle.

The cylinder will need to have its central axis pointing in the same direction as a vector going from the origin to the midpoint and rotation is done by passing Euler angles to a plotting tool.

How do I calculate the Euler angles given this information? I've tried the following in python, but the angles are still wrong:

```
import numpy as np

def calcRotation(phi,theta):

    v1 = np.array([0, 0, 1])
    v2 = np.array([np.sin(theta)*np.cos(phi), np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi), np.cos(phi)])
    Z = np.cross(v1,v2)
    Z /= np.sqrt(Z[0]**2 + Z[1]**2 + Z[2]**2)
    Y = np.cross(Z,v1)
    t = m.atan2(-Z[1],Z[2])
    p = m.asin(Z[0])
    psi = m.atan2(-Y[0],v1[0])
    return np.array([t, p, psi])
```

I wrote this function by following the steps outlined here:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/298940-how-to-calculate-roll-pitch-and-yaw-from-xyz-coordinates-of-3-planar-points

Can someone please explain to me how I get the three Euler angles? Thank you!

Comment: Looks to me like you are following the prescription correctly.  I would then take a look at how you are defining the input vectors.  Make sure they are consistent with the prescription.  And one really dumb question: You aren't by chance confusing degrees and radians?  I do that myself every once in a while.

Comment: I've made sure that my angles are in radians. I'm not sure if my v1 vector is correct. The first rotation is done with theta and the second rotation is done with phi. But I've also tried with v1 = <1, 0, 0> and v1 = <0, 1, 0> but neither of those gave the correct orientation for my cylinder.

Comment: Another straw to grasp at: What happens if you take v1=<-1,0,0> or <0,-1,0> etc?